# How to create the complex representation from magnitude and phase information to perform an inverse fast fourier transform(IFFT)?

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I have a problem with converting amplitude and phase data into the complex form, which is required to perform an IFFT. (inverse fast fourier transform). This is the only data I have.

My frequency range goes from 0.1 to 2.6 and, with 200 samples. I would like to use IFFT to obtain a time signal. How do I convert this magnitude and phase dataset into the complex plane?

I have never used IFFT (Or fft) before, so some helpful insights would be very helpful!

Comment: Closest duplicate I can find, but how you represent the complex data from its magnitude and phase counterparts are in the duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the complex representation like this:

```
a = 3+4i; 
magnitude = abs(a);
phase = angle(a);
```

you should have magnitude = 5, and theta = 0.9273

Now to inverse and obtain back your complex representation, use the formula:

```
 z = magnitude*exp(i*phase)
```

if all goes correctly, you should have the complex representation back.